# Typescript define the type of a POST request response

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, post, typeerror

I have a post request using got like this:

```
const got = got_.extend({
  prefixUrl: serviceUrl,
  responseType: 'json'
})

const { body } = await got.post('newAddress', {
  json: {
    userId
  }
})
```

Body is always either be an object with EITHER the property "newAddress" or with the properties "errorCode" and "newAddress". If it's newAddress it's just a string. If it's error it's an object with an errorcode and an error message

```
type ResponseError = {
  error: {
    errorCode: string
    message: string
  }
  newAddress?: never
}

type AddressResponse = {
  newAddress: string
  error?: never
}

type NewAddressResponse = AddressResponse | ResponseError
```

This is how I currently use the **body** constant:

```
if (body.error) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(body.error))
    return res.json({ newAddress: body.newAddress })
```

**What is the correct way of using my type NewAddressResponse?**

Currently I tried this:
`const { body }: { body: NewAddressResponse } = await got.post ...`

But I have the error:

```
Type 'Response<string>' is not assignable to type '{ body: NewAddressResponse; }'.
  Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NewAddressResponse'.
```

It says got.post returns the type `CancelableRequest<Response<string>>` but I already set the responseType as 'json', above.

**How do I correctly assign types to the response of this got.post?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`got` support generic type, so you can pass your type - `NewAddressResponse` to `post()` for inferring

```
const { body } = await got.post<NewAddressResponse>('newAddress', {
  json: {
    userId
  }
})
```